# Protractor ElementFinder/ElementArrayFinder understanding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

Learning AngularJS from a book and there was an example of simple Protractor test:

```
    it('Should redirect to #/posts/1/sample-title1', function () {
        var posts = element.all(by.repeater('post in posts'));
        posts.first().then(function (postElem) {
            postElem.findElement(by.tagName('a')).then(function (a) {
                a.click(); 
                expect(protractor.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('/posts/1/sample-title1');
            });
        });
    });
```

It didn't work and threw an error: Failed: undefined is not a function

Not sure what was wrong, dig into the Protractor documentation and figured out a solution that work, which is:

```
it('Should redirect to #/posts/1/sample-title1', function () {
    var link = element.all(by.repeater('post in posts')).first().element(by.tagName('a'));
    link.click();
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('/posts/1/sample-title1');
  });
});
```

I'm happy that it works, however I don't quite understand why it work, still the documentation isn't very helpful here (or I'm just too tired at the moment).

Seems that I don't understand the difference between .findElement and .element

When I change the line:

```
var link = element.all(by.repeater('post in posts')).first().element(by.tagName('a'));
```

To:

```
var link = element.all(by.repeater('post in posts')).first().getWebElement().findElement(by.tagName('a'));
```

It also works, however it doesn't work when it's:

```
var link = element.all(by.repeater('post in posts')).first().findElement(by.tagName('a'));
```

Can someone explain this ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are differences to each of those functions. In your first case you got an `error: Failed: undefined is not a function` because the usage of `.first()` was incorrect. [`first()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.first) function returns an `ElementFinder` and not a promise.

- This means that there is no promise to be resolved on it using `.then()`.
- You can chain it with other ElementFinder dependent operations like `element()`, `$$`, `getText()`, etc.

Next, the lines that you wrote -

```
var link1 = element.all(by.repeater('post in posts')).first().element(by.tagName('a'));
var link2 = element.all(by.repeater('post in posts')).first().getWebElement().findElement(by.tagName('a'));
var link3 = element.all(by.repeater('post in posts')).first().findElement(by.tagName('a'));
```

**Explanation -**

1. `.findElement()` works on top of two instances, one is an [`element`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.findElement) and the other one is a [`browser`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.findElement) or [`driver`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.findElement).

   - `link1` works because it has an `element()` (which is also an ElementFinder) function chained to another ElementFinder and its valid.
   - `link2` is valid in its syntax because `findElement()` is chained to [`getWebElement()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.getWebElement). As explained above this is valid because `getWebElement()` returns an `element`.
   - However your `link3` doesn't work because the syntax chaining of function/method is improper. `findElement()` is neither chained to an `element` nor a `browser` instance, but it is chained to an `ElementFinder` and so you get an error while you use it.
2. [`.element()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder) is an ElementFinder and so works when used alone or chained with other `ElementArrayFinder` or `ElementFinder`. `link1` is an example of that. Valid syntaxes for ElementFinder -

   ```
   element(LOCATOR);
   element(LOCATOR1).element(LOCATOR2);
   element.all(PARENT_LOCATOR).element(LOCATOR);
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank for the detailed explanation, it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

FindElement is a webdriver.webElement function, so you must use it after a webElement which is why it doesn't work in your last example.  The documentation in the protractor API may help you for webdriver.WebElement.findElement:

http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.findElement